# After installing jenkins in ICP (IBM Cloud Private) from Catalog its not becoming available

Tags: jenkins, ibm-cloud-private

Installing Jenkins from ICP catalog successfully deploys but showing not ready & not available, hence not able to launch it.

I have Enterprise version of ICP available with me. I was following [tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/garage/dte/tutorial/set-jenkins-pipeline-continuously-integrate-and-deliver-kubernetes-deployments-ibm-cloud) on my hosted ICP

I installed bluecompute-ce it was installed and became available in 3-5 minutes. As per tutorial it says jenkins is already available which was not in my case I tried installing it using the same steps but after installation I see Jenkins is deployed by its showing not ready & not available (Ready & Available column showing 0).

[image]

Dont know what is the problem exactly.

Ready & Available column should show 1 as its showing in others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue. I was not creating persistent volume before deploying jenkins. there are two ways to make it. Either uncheck create persistent volume option if you want it to be there then first create persistent volume and add details of it.